# Maven 1.0.2 and JDK 1.6 issue

Tags: maven, java-6

I'm working with Maven 1.0.2 and JDK 1.5 for some time without any problems. I decided to migrate to JDK 1.6 so I've changed the JAVA_HOME enviroment variable (on Windows 7 system) and now I receive a strange error message when trying to use maven (maven install command in cmd, for example).

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "command.com": CreateProcess error=2, the
system could not find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:460)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:593)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute$Java13CommandLauncher.exec(Exec
ute.java:646)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute.launch(Execute.java:416)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute.execute(Execute.java:427)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute.getProcEnvironment(Execute.java
:180)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Property.loadEnvironment(Property.java:
455)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Property.execute(Property.java:359)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:341)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.ant.AntTag.doTag(AntTag.java:185)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.run(TagScript.java:279)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:135)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.TagSupport.invokeBody(TagSupport.java:233)
    at com.werken.werkz.jelly.ProjectTag.doTag(ProjectTag.java:112)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.run(TagScript.java:279)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginManager.runScript(PluginManager.java:11
43)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginManager.attainGoals(PluginManager.java:
647)
    at org.apache.maven.MavenSession.attainGoals(MavenSession.java:263)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.App.doMain(App.java:488)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.App.main(App.java:1239)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.werken.forehead.Forehead.run(Forehead.java:551)
    at com.werken.forehead.Forehead.main(Forehead.java:581)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, O sistema nÒo pode encont
rar o arquivo especificado
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:81)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:30)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:453)
```

There isn't a command.com file on Windows 7, it's cmd.exe instead. I don't know why maven searches for it only when I point to JDK 1.6. If I point JAVA_HOME back to JDK 1.5, everything comes back to normal. What is happening? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, still at this version because I'm using an old [AndroMDA](http://www.andromda.org/docs/index.html) plugin at a project.

Comment: I don't know why this happens, I guess Java 1.5 returns a different OS name than 1.6 which leads ANT to build the wrong command line, but honestly: Is this setup worth the debugging (EOL Java, ancient Maven, old plugin version)? If it is a legacy project, don't change anything. If it is an active project, update everything.

Comment: @his I've just tried to run maven at Ubuntu 11.04 to compile the same project with JDK 1.6 and everything went just fine! I think you're right and JDK 1.6 returns a different OS than JDK 1.5 on Windows 7 and ANT gets lost when compiling the project. Thank you.

Comment: Using an OS where the CLI name and command line building did not change is a nice workaround :-).

Answer (score 5):

windows 7 x64 does not have command.com since it is a 16bit application i had the same problem, and a friend of mine found out a brilliant sollution

copy cmd.exe and rename the copy as command.com, put it in the path

Problem solved!!!